# Edit javascript code to enable right-click and copy paste in web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, right-click, inspect-element

How can I edit this piece of code so that the right- click and the context-menu that have been disabled are re-enabled? I have no knowledge of javascript or any other back-end language. This code is from my university's javaelab website in which they have disabled right click and copy paste.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../flag.checker.php',
        success: function(codedata) {
            if(codedata == 1) {
             console.log("Diasble");

                $("body").on("contextmenu",function(e){
                   window.alert("NOT ALLOWED");
                    return false;
                });

                $('body').bind('cut copy paste', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    window.alert("NOT ALLOWED");
                     return false;
                });

                editor.on('paste',function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    console.log('Paste is clicked');
                });


                editor.on('beforeChange',function(instance,changeObj) {
                    if(changeObj.origin == "paste") {
                        window.alert("NOT ALLOWED");
                        changeObj.cancel();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Do you want to edit this code or adding another code to stop those effects?

Answer (score 5):

In the address bar of your browser, type:

```
javascript: $( "body" ).off();
```

And press enter. If the copy paste doesn't work:

```
javascript: $( "body" ).off("cut copy paste", "**");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to edit the code, you want to simply remove all of it, as it's all designed to prevent copy and paste.

If this is a site that you want to copy and paste from but can't modify the source (e.g. You're not hosting it) then your easiest route would to be to use a Web proxy (e.g. Telerik Fiddler) and add a custom response to that request - essentially returning `0` whenever a request is made to something ending in `flag.checker.php`. This wonderful approach requires no code changes.